# search box in master page with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, master-pages

How can I send search text from textbox witch is available in Master Page. Master page referred from all pages. So I can't able to give Module and controller for all other pages.

So Can you please guide me how we can achieve this task by using angularjs module.

Comment: Please provide more detailed explanation of what you need to do along with some page structure code. Question is far too broad

Comment: you can put your search term in $rootScope

Comment: I am using the Layout.cshtml page. In that page I have search box and search button. In Index.cshtml file I have the code for displaying the Items by using ng-init method with web api call. So here I have faced how can send the text box from layout page to index page by using angular js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular events to do that. You can send a event with an identifier, and hear this event in yout controllers. Something like that:

**Emit event**

`$scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);`

**Intercept events**

```
$scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) { console.log(mass); });
```

As you can see, you can pass any elements that you want. So you can send your text/message to another controller using this events.